# Getting data object from the dialog in Vaadin

Tags: event-handling, dialog, vaadin

I have written a class for my Vaadin application that extends Dialog.
The dialog panel contains several text fields, couple date pickers, etc.
The purpose of this dialog is to build an instance of Filter class.
Here is the piece of code. The whole class is too big to be shown here.

```
public class FilterPanel extends Dialog {

private Filter filter;

private TextField nameField;
private TextField countryField;
private DatePicker postingDateField;
private TextField fromYear;
private TextField toYear;
private ComboBox tagField;

public FilterPanel() {
    buildDialog();
}

public FilterPanel(Filter filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
}
```

It all works well and object is being build correctly.
My problem is that I can't get this object out of this dialog after it is being closed.
I am closing it explicitly by calling close() function.
I placed Dialog.DialogCloseActionEvent listener into the calling class but it is not being called.

```
    @Override
protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
    super.onAttach(attachEvent); 
    registration = ComponentUtil.addListener(attachEvent.getUI(), DialogCloseActionEvent.class,
            event -> {
                Dialog source = event.getSource();
                if(source instanceof FilterPanel) {
                    reader = ((FilterPanel)source).getFilter();
                }
            });
}
```

I am opening this dialog from the button click listener and tried to call getFilter() method just after showing the dialog.

```
        this.filterButton.addClickListener((ClickEvent<Button> clickEvent) -> {
        FilterPanel fp = config.getFilterPanel(filter);
        fp.open();
        filter = fp.getFilter();
    });
```

However it always returns null. I placed a breakpoint in the debugger on this line and it is being called before the dialog opens. According to the documentation, Dialog by default is suppose to be modal.
How do I make it work? Help me please.

Comment: Can you please show the code where you create the dialog and add the close listener'

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Dialog.DialogCloseActionEvent and not Dialog.OpenedChangedEvent?

Comment: I added code to my post. 
@Tatu Lund: Why OpenedChangedEvent is better? I do need to get data out after dialog is close complete.

Comment: Read the JavaDoc of addDialogCloseActionListener. This event is not dispatched when Dialog is closed, but when user clicks outside dialog or presses Esc, so that you can yourself decide whether to close it or not. OpenedChangedEvent  is dispatched when Dialog is opened and cclosed.

Comment: I did try to click outside the dialog. Event wasn't fired either. Not sure if I have registered for the event correctly. I used a sample from the cookbook.
I am also thinking about using property change event similar to Swing, but Vaadin doesn't have PropertyChangeSupport interface and therefore I don't know how to use it and haven't found any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try to use Dialog.OpenedChangedEvent and it didn't work as I need it.
While Dialog.DialogCloseActionEvent wasn't fired at all did fire but not at the right moment.
Eventually I wrote my own extension of ComponentEvent and fire it explicitly when I need it. It does work for me well